# Can't install VirtualBox Guest Additions on CentOS7 (with kernel 4.4)

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I installed kernel 4.4 from ELRepo, along with `kernel-lt-tools`, `kernel-lt-devel` & `kernel-lt-headers`.  I also installed `dkms`.

`vboxadd-install.log` contains this:

```
grep: Unmatched ) or \)
```

The vboxadd-setup.log file contains this:

```
Error building the module:
modprobe vboxguest failed
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `(`. Joking aside, is there a line number associated with that `grep` error? It seems `grep` wants to interpret some kind of regular expression, but trips up on the way.

Answer (score 0):

At least gcc and make are required, and if missing give errors building virtualbox guest additions

```
sudo yum install perl gcc dkms kernel-devel kernel-headers make bzip2
```